# store multiple value in a single array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a part of my code

```
$try = "<a href='{$linkURL}'>{$className}</a> w/ {$staffName} {$startDateTime} - {$endDateTime}";
echo $try;
```

that is responsible for printing  data like this (it is just a part of data, the original one contains long list of similar output):

```
Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00
Private Class w/ Cheyenne 2015-03-17 18:30:00 - 2015-03-17 19:30:00
Trial Class w/ Speed 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00
```

I wanted this data in an array so i tried something like this:

```
$arr4 = array_merge(array($try));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr4);
echo '</pre>';
```

This started to print data in this form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00

)

Array
(
    [0] => Private Class w/ Cheyenne 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00

)

Array
(
    [0] => Trial Class w/ Speed 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00

)
```

It is forming different array, can anyone please tell how i can get the data stored in a single array, and get something like this(may be close to it):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00
    [1] =>  Private Class w/ Cheyenne 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00
    [2] =>  Private Class w/ Speed 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00
)
```

Comment: `$arr4 = array_column($arr4, 0);` But why did you use the array_merge() in the first place?

Comment: are you assigning this inside a loop? no need for `array_merge`, just assign it like you normally would do `$container[] = 'whatever string this is';`

Comment: @Ghost yes it is inside foreach loop. now i am getting data like this:  Array([0]=>Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00) Array( [0]=>Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00   [1] =>  Private Class w/ Cheyenne 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00)Array(   [0] => Trial Class w/ Class Cancelled 2015-03-17 19:30:00 - 2015-03-17 20:15:00  [1]=> Private Class w/ Cheyenne 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00    [2]=> Private Class w/ Speed 2015-03-24 18:30:00 - 2015-03-24 19:30:00) , can i get 1 array widout any repetition

Comment: @MarkBaker i got an error  Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Comment: [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) was introduced in PHP 5.5.0 (nearly 2 years ago). What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be:

```
$array = array();

// Your line logic might be
foreach ($lines as $line) {

    // Add '$array[] ='  before each line
    $array[] = $try = "<a href='{$linkURL}'>{$className}</a> w/ {$staffName} {$startDateTime} - {$endDateTime}";

    echo $try;
}


// when all lines are created you will have a single array with an entry per line
print_r($array);
```

The `$array[]` would add the line as a new entry to the array as well.

### Making the array multidimensional

```
$array = array();

// Your line logic might be
foreach ($lines as $line) {

    $try = "<a href='{$linkURL}'>{$className}</a> w/ {$staffName} {$startDateTime} - {$endDateTime}";
    echo $try;

    // Create multidimensional record
    $lineForArray = array(
        'linkUrl' => $linkURL,
        'className' => $className,
        'staffName' => $staffName,
        'startDateTime' => $startDateTime,
        'endDateTime' => $endDateTime
    );
    $array[] = $lineForArray;
}


// when all lines are created you will have a single array with an entry per line
print_r($array);
```

Comment: i am getting the result in same format as i was getting earlier i need to merge all the result in single array so that i can fetch data easily

Comment: Uhm, how can that be, initiate the array outside the block in which you generate all lines (loop or something) updated the answer

Comment: BTW, `$array[]` is equal to `array_push($array, ...)` in the other answer

Comment: thanks, i would like to ask one more thing, in the $array[] statement, u must have noticed that i have 4 variable $className, $staffName, $startDateTime, $endDateTime, is it possible to arrangs it furthur like this:  Array([0]=>Array([className]=>Trial Class[staffName]=>Class Cancelled[startDateTime] => 2015-03-17 19:30:00[endDateTime] => 2015-03-17 20:15:00) [1] => Array([className] => Private Class[staffName] => Cheyenne[startDateTime] => 2015-03-24 18:30:00[endDateTime] => 2015-03-24 19:30:00))

Comment: I added that to the solution...NOW :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the reason of doing this:

```
$arr4 = array_merge(array($try));
```

You are treating every $try string as an array, when you want a single array with that strings as values.

Try using array_push() function and see the output, maybe this is what you need.

```
//Initializing the array
$arr4 = array();
//and now for each $try string you want to store:
array_push($arr4, $try);
```

Regards

Comment: when i am tried ur method i got this error,  Warning: array_push() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.. can u plz luk thru it

Comment: Should be `array_push($arr4, $try);` Assuming you already initialized the array